# How do I create a shared directory under root?

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, access-control-list

I'm trying to create a shared folder on my root partition that anyone in a particular group can read and write to and any new files within that folder are also read writeable by anyone in that group no matter what. I've managed  to create a folder whereby new users can write to it - but any new files are read only to the group.

Steps I've taken:

```
mkdir /storage
chown -R root:storage-public /storage
chmod -R 2775 /storage
touch test.txt
```

But these are the permissions I'm getting from my test file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root storage-public 13 Oct 12 21:59 test.txt
```

Can anyone help?

Also worth mentioning that I've tried doing this under ACLs but it seems that the posix permissions override the ACL and I get an effective line next to the output of getfacl.

Comment: didn't you want to  `touch /storage/test.txt`  && `ls -la /storage/test.txt`?

Comment: What's the `umask` set to?

Comment: @dusan.bajic - yeah but I'm already in the directory so it's not necessary to specify the path. Umask is set to 0002

Answer (score 0):

You have the `setgid` flag on, which is supposed to have group permissions inherited. *However* this only applies if the person creating the file is in that group.

Since you created the file `test.txt` are you are of the `storage-public group`?